# Superglobals are null on XAMPP, PHP 7.0.9 and virtual host

Tags: php, xampp, php-7

I have a problem with Superglobals.

The values of all of them (SERVER, POST, GET, SESSION, COOKIE) are NULL
For example dump on $_SERVER return

```
array (size=42)
  'MIBDIRS' => null
  'MYSQL_HOME' => null
  'OPENSSL_CONF' => null
  'PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR' => null
  'PHPRC' => null
  'TMP' => null
  'HTTP_HOST' => null
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => null
  'HTTP_ACCEPT' => null
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => null
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => null
  'HTTP_REFERER' => null
  'HTTP_COOKIE' => null
  'HTTP_CONNECTION' => null
  'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' => null
  'PATH' => null
  'SystemRoot' => null
  'COMSPEC' => null
  'PATHEXT' => null
  'WINDIR' => null
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => null
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => null
  'SERVER_NAME' => null
  'SERVER_ADDR' => null
  'SERVER_PORT' => null
  'REMOTE_ADDR' => null
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => null
  'REQUEST_SCHEME' => null
  'CONTEXT_PREFIX' => null
  'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => null
  'SERVER_ADMIN' => null
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => null
  'REMOTE_PORT' => null
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => null
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => null
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => null
  'QUERY_STRING' => null
  'REQUEST_URI' => null
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => null
  'PHP_SELF' => null
  'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => null
  'REQUEST_TIME' => null
```

The system is Windows 7 + XAMPP + PHP 7.0.9 and virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "d:/php/test
    <Directory />
      Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ServerName http://test.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

And hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 test.com
```

Comment: This is definitely strange. In your `php.ini` file are you [auto-prepending](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) a file which sets them to null?

Comment: Can you please show us the relevant parts of your `php.ini`? Ex. auto_globals_jit, register_globals etc.

Comment: register_globals=Off, auto_globals_jit=On

Comment: The problem is solved. Bug in a "security" module I use in the code.